# Is there a polite and natural way to welcome the stranger you've already met today?

Tags: word-choice, british-english, greetings

Is there a polite and natural way to welcome the stranger you've already met today? A usual greeting seems inappropriate since you've already seen the person. Even if it was a brief encounter (in a pharmacy, in a grocery store, or somewhere at reception) and that person didn't remember you, is there a way to hint we've seen each other today?

Would 'again' be appropriate in this context?

> Hi, again.
>
> Hello, it's me again.
>
> Good/nice to see you again. (it doesn't imply this day, though)

What are other alternatives? How do you say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with saying something like "Hello again", even if the second meeting occurred some time after the first.  "Again" tells the person that you recall the first meeting.

Some fun alternatives (usually said playfully)

> We have to stop meeting like this.
>
> It seems we keep bumping into each other.
>
> Twice in one day!  What a nice surprise.
>
> I have the strangest feeling we've met before.

Of course, if it's someone without a sense of humor, then stick with something more formal:

> What a pleasant surprise, seeing you again.

Note that your inflection can imply that you are happy to see them again, or that you are *not* happy to see them again.  For example:

> (spoken with heavy irony) Oh, it's you.  Hello again.  This must be my lucky day.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Would *"What a pleasant surprise **to see** you again."* work too or do you prefer "seeing" to "to see" here?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  Either way.  There are many options, too many to list them all.

Answer (score 2):

"Hello again" is the simplest option. You can use it in all kinds of situations to end or begin a conversation, just as long as you've already met the person before.

"Good/nice/great to see you again" is another option, but I would only use it when you haven't seen the person for a while (at least 3 days, depending on how you know the person).

Whether or not you use *again*, saying "Nice to see you" implies you have seen them before. Using *again* simply drives home the point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what did you mean by "drives home the point"?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko the question mentioned that the person didn't remember you, so to add "again" is almost rudely pointing that out, whereas the "nice to see you" in this answer only hints at that.

Comment: @WeatherVane "nice to see you" doesn't imply this day, does it? I am looking for something as in "we've chatted today, here we are again"... (can I say "here we are again", btw?)

Comment: Perhaps "didn't we meet earlier?" As though you are the one who is uncertain, and it gives the other an opportunity to recall, or deny it if they don't care to take it up.